# Rendering of WebPartZone

Tags: publishing-page, web-part

How can I prevent a WebPartZone from wrapping with `<table>`?
For web accessibility we don't want WebParts to be wrapped in tables.

Comment: Can you give a few more details on "...from wrapping with ?..."  A Web Part Zone will expand/contract to fit the height/width of the Web Part(s) inside of it, possibly causing.  You can force the Web Part(s) to have a specific size tuned to the height/width of your users average resolution to control wrapping or scrolling.

Comment: Sorry, I had written <table>, but forgot to set it as source.
The main problem is that WebpartZone wrap all WebParts in a couple of tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the HTML you can add a control adapter to your web part zone control.

[Here is a link to a blog post where this is done](http://blog.sharepoint.ch/2007/12/webpartzone-adapter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my experience is that WebPartZone always renders those tables. If you want to conform to accessibility standards, you will have to ditch web part zones.

See the accessibility section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartzone.aspx

Comment: This is very bad news :(